# combine multiple dataframes in a csv file separating each with an empty row

Tags: python, pandas

how can I separate each dataframe with an empty row
ive combined them using this snippet

```
frames1 = [df4, df5, df6]  
Summary = pd.concat(frames1)
```

so how can i split them with an empty row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below example which works:

Create test dfs

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,20).reshape(5,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,20).reshape(5,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,20).reshape(5,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
```

---

Solution:

```
pd.concat([df.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True) for df in dfs])
```

---

```
      A     B     C     D
0  17.0  16.0  15.0   7.0
1  13.0   6.0  12.0  18.0
2   0.0   2.0  10.0  17.0
3   8.0  13.0  10.0  17.0
4   4.0  18.0   8.0  19.0
5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
0  14.0   0.0  13.0  12.0
1  10.0   3.0   6.0   3.0
2  15.0  10.0  15.0   3.0
3   9.0  16.0  11.0   4.0
4   5.0   7.0   6.0   2.0
5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
0  10.0  18.0  13.0  12.0
1   1.0   6.0  10.0   0.0
2   2.0  19.0   4.0  18.0
3   4.0   3.0   9.0  16.0
4  16.0   6.0   5.0   6.0
5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

For horizontal stack:

```
pd.concat([df.assign(test=np.nan) for df in dfs],axis=1)
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D  test   A   B   C   D  test   A   B   C   D  test
0  17  16  15   7   NaN  14   0  13  12   NaN  10  18  13  12   NaN
1  13   6  12  18   NaN  10   3   6   3   NaN   1   6  10   0   NaN
2   0   2  10  17   NaN  15  10  15   3   NaN   2  19   4  18   NaN
3   8  13  10  17   NaN   9  16  11   4   NaN   4   3   9  16   NaN
4   4  18   8  19   NaN   5   7   6   2   NaN  16   6   5   6   NaN
```

Comment: do you know how to separate them with column instead of a row ?

Comment: good, maybe some keys parameter, MultiIndex and flatten columns should be nice for prevent duplicated columns names

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?:

```
fname = 'test2.csv'

frames1 = [df4, df5, df6]
with open(fname, mode='a+') as f:
    for df in frames1:
        df.to_csv(fname, mode='a', header = f.tell() == 0)
        f.write('\n')
```

`test2.csv`:

```
,a,b,c
0,0,1,2
1,3,4,5
2,6,7,8

0,0,1,2
1,3,4,5
2,6,7,8

0,0,1,2
1,3,4,5
2,6,7,8
```

`f.tell() == 0` checks whether the file handle is at the beginning of the file, i.e. at 0, if yes, prints header, else doesn't.

**NOTE:** I have used same values for all the `df`s, that's why all the results are similar.

### For columns:

```
fname = 'test3.csv'
frames1 = [df1, df2, df3]
Summary = pd.concat([df.assign(**{'  ':' '}) for df in frames1], axis=1)
Summary.to_csv(fname)
```

`test3.csv`:

```
,a,b,c,  ,a,b,c,  ,a,b,c,  
0,0,1,2, ,0,1,2, ,0,1,2, 
1,3,4,5, ,3,4,5, ,3,4,5, 
2,6,7,8, ,6,7,8, ,6,7,8,
```

But the columns will not be equally spaced. If you save with `header=False`:
`test3.csv`:

```
0,0,1,2, ,0,1,2, ,0,1,2, 
1,3,4,5, ,3,4,5, ,3,4,5, 
2,6,7,8, ,6,7,8, ,6,7,8,
```

Comment: how to separate them with column too ?

Comment: @ashrafkhaled Edited, please check.